# Difference between a lambda term and a lambda expression

Tags: terminology, lambda-calculus

Is there any difference between a $\lambda$-term and a $\lambda$-expression?

Looking at the recursive definitions on Wikipedia of 
[$\lambda$-term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Lambda_terms) and [$\lambda$-expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Definition), they are equivalent. But I am confused as they are slightly different and refer to what they define by a different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Books on lambda calculus define only lambda terms. Some programming languages may call anonymous function lambda expressions.